ubuntu 22.04 rebuild kernel after error while installind cuda for nvidia 1050 gtx ti
I have on my SSD Disk two ubuntu verison

ubuntu 22.04
ubuntu 24.04

while installing cuda for nvidia on ubuntu 22.04 and after restart i had problems like ethernet and wirelss and bluetooth stopped working and i lost the control of screen display setting
I tried to rebuild ubuntu kernel by installing packages and building it using dpkg ...
but the packages found ubuntu 24.04 kernel and edited its boot and packages but the desired system ubuntu 22.04 still in the same problem how can i solve it

How did you install CUDA?  Never accept any Nvidia drivers from the CUDA install, all the Nvidia setup should take place first with drivers from the Ubuntu repositories.  Several answers on this site for running the Nvidia script to install CUDA without changing system files.
